# Nouns Followed by Infinitives sentences

Tags: infinitives

Sentences given below have a **Nouns Followed by Infinitives.**

can anyone please explain the sentneces' meaning?

1) The decision to increase taxes was not popular.

2) Permission to enter the area was difficult to get.

Thanks,

Charmi

Comment: Can't you make out the meanings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two nouns in your examples, *decision* and *permission* are derived from the verbs *decide* and *permit*.

Both of these verbs are *catenative* or "chaining" verbs: they take as their complements clauses headed by other verbs, which are cast as marked infinitives:

> They decided **to raise** taxes.
>   They permitted us **to enter** the area.

<sup>Note that you can in fact **chain** these verbs together:</sup>

> <sup>They decided **to permit** us **to enter** the area.</sup>

The nouns derived from these verbs take the same infinitival complements:

> decision **to raise** taxes
>   permission **to enter**

In effect the infinitival clauses act as modifiers telling you *which* decision, *which* permission; but they're not: they're complements to the nouns.

Comment: *We expect the bank manager **to** decide **to** authorise us **to** borrow more **to** enable us **to** enter the housing market...*